# Splitting an infinite unordered sum (both directions)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, absolute-convergence

This question is a follow-up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387103/splitting-an-infinite-series).

Let $A, B_1, B_2, \dots$ be countable sets such that $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}B_i = A$ and the $B_i$'s are disjoint. Let $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ take elements of $A$ to the reals. The claim is that $$\sum_{w \in A} f(w) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{w \in B_i} f(w),$$ where the left-hand side converges if and only if the right-hand side converges. I am using this definition of $\sum_{w \in S} f(w)$:

> We say that $\sum_{w \in S} f(w) = T$ (converges to $T$) if for each $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists finite subset $F \subseteq S$ such that for all finite $G$ satisfying $F \subseteq G \subseteq S$ we have $|\sum_{w \in G} f(w) - T| < \varepsilon$.

In the original question I only needed that left-hand side converges $\implies$ right-hand side converges. I wonder if the other direction can be proven too? Here is my proof of the first direction:

We first note that $\sum_{w \in B_i} f(w)$ converges for each $B_i$ since $B_i \subseteq A$.

Now let $\sum_{w \in A} f(w) = S$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. So there exists finite $F \subseteq A$ such that for all finite $G$ satisfying $F \subseteq G \subseteq A$, we have $|\sum_{w \in G} f(w) - S| < \varepsilon/2$.

Let $J = \{i \in \mathbb{N} : F \cap B_i \neq \emptyset\}$ so $J \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is finite. Now let $K$ be an arbitrary finite superset of $J$ such that $J \subseteq K \subseteq \mathbb{N}$.

For each $i \in K$, we can find finite $C_i \subseteq B_i$ such that $|\sum_{w \in C_i} f(w) - \sum_{w \in B_i} f(w)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2|K|}$ and $B_i \cap F \subseteq C_i$. Thus,

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|\sum_{i \in K} \sum_{w \in B_i} f(w) - S\right|
&\leq& \left|\sum_{i \in K} \sum_{w \in C_i} f(w) - \sum_{i \in K} \sum_{w \in B_i} f(w)\right| + \left|\sum_{i \in K} \sum_{w \in C_i} f(w) - S\right|\\
&<& |K|\frac{\varepsilon}{2|K|} + \varepsilon/2\\
&=& \varepsilon
\end{eqnarray*}.$$

For the other direction, the main problem is finding the finite subset $F \subseteq A$. I am unable to find one that works. Is it provable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other direction is false. For a counterexample, let $B_i=\{i\}\times\mathbb N$, let $f((i,1))=1$ and $f((i,2))=-1$ and the remaining values any sufficiently convergent sequences, e.g. $f((i,j))=2^{-i-j}$.

Then the right-hand side converges, but there are infinitely many values of $1$, so you can't pick the required finite set for any $\epsilon$.

Comment: Or $f((i,j))=0$ for $j\not \in\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Oh wow that's a nice counterexample! I like the simplification from @WimC too. Now I need to look for additional conditions that make the other direction true. Actually I'm trying to show that the two definitions for expectation for discrete random variable $X$, $\sum_{w \in S} P(w)X(w)$ and $\sum_{u \in \text{range}(X)} \sum_{X(w)=u} P(w)X(w)$ are equivalent. Clearly this must be true? So if the expected value exists based on the second definition, it should exist based on the first too. Do you know what's the required condition here?